# Resnet50 image preprocessing

Tags: tensorflow, feature-extraction, resnet, tensorflow-hub

I am using `https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/3` to extract image feature vectors. However, I'm confused when it comes to how to preprocess the images prior to passing them through the module.

Based on the related [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/docs/common_signatures/images.md) explanation, it's said that the following should be done:

```
image_path = "path/to/the/jpg/image"
image_string = tf.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)

# All other transformations (during training), in my case:
image = tf.random_crop(image, [224, 224, 3])
image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)

# During testing:
image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, 224, 224)
```

However, using the aforementioned transformation, the results I am getting suggest that something might be wrong. Moreover, the [Resnet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) is saying that the images should be preprocessed by:

> A 224×224 crop is randomly sampled from an image or its
> horizontal flip, with the per-pixel mean subtracted...

which I can't quite understand what is means. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Looking forward to you answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image modules on TensorFlow Hub all expect pixel values in range [0,1], like you get in your code snippet above. This makes it easy and safe to switch between modules.

Inside the module, the input values are scaled to the range that the network was trained for. The module https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/3 has been published from a TF-Slim checkpoint (see documentation), which uses yet another convention for normalizing inputs than He&al. -- but all this is taken care of.

To demystify the language in He&al.: it refers to the mean R, G and B values aggregated over all pixels of the dataset they studied, following the old wisdom that normalizing inputs to zero mean helps neural networks train better. However, later papers on image classification no longer expended this degree of attention to dataset-specific preprocessing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you point me to a reference where `Inside the module, the input values are scaled to the range that the network was trained for.` this is mentioned?

Comment: The link to github that you give has the interface definition. It's up to the module whether there is a separate scaling step (as you can find in saved_model.pb if you disassemble the resnet module) or whether that's achieved by having weights and biases trained accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The citation from the Resnet paper you mentioned is based on the following explanation from the [Alexnet paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf):

> ImageNet consists of variable-resolution images, while our system requires a constant input dimensionality. Therefore,  we down-sampled the images to a fixed resolution of256×256. Given a rectangular image, we first rescaled the image such that the shorter side was of length 256, and thencropped out the central 256×256patch from the resulting image. We did not pre-process the images in any other way, except for subtracting the mean activity over the training set from each pixel.

So in the Resnet paper, a similar process consist in taking a of 224x224 pixels part of the image (or of its horizontally flipped version) to ensure the network is given constant-sized images, and then center it by substracting the mean.